# How do I stop objects from re-arranging my keys?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Assuming I have this code below:

```js
const list = [22, 13, 17, 11, 0];
let obj = {};

for (let val of list) {
  obj[val] = false;
}

console.log(obj);
```

The result is:

```
{
 0:false,
 11:false,
 13:false,
 17:false,
 22:false
}
```

It re-arranges the original order in the list. How do I stop it from doing so?

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Comment: Fundamentally, an object is not for storing ordered data. This is the major difference between [keyed collections](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-keyed-collections) and [indexed collections](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-indexed-collections). Use an [Array](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead. Alternatively, use a [Map](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead which also guarantees insertion order.